# How to fit content inside a background-image

Tags: html, css

How would one ensure that certain content is always fitted inside a particular area of a web page?

As an example, I would like the sentence "Fit this inside" to appear inside of the background image. Here is my `test.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <body>Fit this inside</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `test.css` file:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('bg_img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:100% 68%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This results in the text "Fit this inside" appearing at the very top of the page, and not inside the background image area.

What is the correct method to do this?

JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/u3TAF/**

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Looks like your background-size (height) is 68% - so it's begins in 16% of the height.  You may locate your text in any block (div/p) and set it's top to 16%.  * edit - it's 16% (32/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my comment higher.
You've set the background image to be 68% height.  set the text into container with same properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body
            {
                background-image: url('image.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size:100% 68%;
            }
            div.container {
                position:absolute;
                top:16%;
                height: 68%;
                left: 0%;
                overflow:auto;
            }        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            Now it's fit!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option would be to put the text within a DIV and then apply the styles to that element. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#test{
    background-image: url('bg_img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:100% 68%;
    overflow: scroll;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
Fit This Inside
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image should be given to the parent element. In your case, in the CSS, attach the background image property to the `<html>` element. So this image would act as a background to **all** the content of this page.

If that is what your aim is, then:

```
    html{
         background: url('bg_img.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, however the text is still outside of the image.